# How to sync my backbone.js app with the changes on server?

Tags: ajax, backbone.js, synchronization

I have an app in backbone.js. The user can add items to the app which are added at the backend server and the collection is refreshed and the user sees the added data. How can I sync the app with any changes in the backend. Suppose if multiple users add the data at the same time each one should see the changes.

There are options like ajax polling where I can refresh the model after a certain time period but I hate to use it.

Can you suggest any event driven method where any change in the backend is reflected immediately in the frontend of my app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a kind of refresh event on your app, which will refresh every few minutes. Something like evernote desktop application does. In that event you would add collection sync event.

You can also use something like

```
collection.sync(method, collection, [options])
```

http://backbonejs.org/#Sync

This doesn't answer your question though, and I'm not sure how you would push changes from server to client.